# Different click events for the same duplicated button?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component with the following HTML:

```
<div id="catalogo" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let artista of artistas" class="col-sm" style="margin-top:20px">
            <div class="card border-dark text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>{{artista.name}}</h5>
                </div>
                <img src={{artista.img}} class="__card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="mb-2">
                        {{artista.emoji}}
                    </h6>

                    <button (click)="onClick()" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-1 mb-1">
                        ℹ️ — Discografia
                    </button>
                    <div *ngIf="this.conteudoVisivel" class="__albumInfo">
                        <hr>
                        <p>{{artista.album[0]}}</p>
                        <p>{{artista.album[1]}}</p>
                        <p>{{artista.album[2]}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This component is shown six times with different information as you can see with text interpolation.

The button is supposed to show or hide the div with the class __albumInfo for its specific card but it influences every card.

[image]

There is more than one button but in the HTML I can only see one, how can I possibly differentiate the copies of the buttons and assign them different click events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a map and leverage the ngFor index for this.
html:

```html
<div
  *ngFor="let artista of artistas; let i = index"
  class="col-sm"
  style="margin-top: 20px"
>
  <div class="card border-dark text-center" style="width: 18rem">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h5>{{artista.name}}</h5>
    </div>
    <img src="{{artista.img}}" class="__card-img-top" alt="..." />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h6 class="mb-2">{{artista.emoji}}</h6>

      <button
        (click)="onClick(i)"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-1 mb-1"
      >
        ℹ️ — Discografia
      </button>
      <div *ngIf="this.conteudoVisivelMap[i]" class="__albumInfo">
        <hr />
        <p>{{artista.album[0]}}</p>
        <p>{{artista.album[1]}}</p>
        <p>{{artista.album[2]}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component:

```js
export class YourComponent {
  conteudoVisivelMap = {};

  onClick(index: number){
   this.conteudoVisivelMap[index] = !this.conteudoVisivelMap[index];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment eko! It worked but I had to make a small change to the component code you provided: conteudoVisivelMap: { [key: number]: boolean} = {};

Comment: Oh sure, my IDE doesn't complain about types so I didn't put any :-)